# GetJSon not suceeding

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

The following code is calling a translator

```
var url = "https://api.lingo24.com/mt/v1/translate";

$.getJSON(url + "?user_key=9e56f5d5e5b5647a32ccb58f7bcd8327&q=test&source=en&target=fr&callback=callback", function (data) {
        alert("success");
        alert(data.translation);
    });
```

user_key    Your User Key

q           Text for translation

source      Language of source text

target      Target language for translated text

I have tried both this way and with the $.ajax but neither is returning a result. The website itself returns a result. If someone has an idea what I am doing wrong I would seriously appreciate it.

**Request**

```
curl -v  -X POST "https://api.lingo24.com/mt/v1/translate" -d 'user_key=9e56f5d5e5b5647a32ccb58f7bcd8327&q=test&source=en&target=fr'
```

**Response Body**

```
{
 "translation": "Testez",
 "success": "true"
}
```

**Response Code**

> 200

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 27 Dec 2014 04:47:18 GMT
Server: openresty
X-3scale-proxy-secret-token: Shared_secret_sent_from_proxy_to_API_backend_71a6eb471024e8db
Content-Length: 68
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: try removing the `callback param` since that typically is used for `jsonp`. Add an error handler to help give more clues also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted this in web browser and found out why it is not working,

https://api.lingo24.com/mt/v1/translate?user_key=9e56f5d5e5b5647a32ccb58f7bcd8327&q=test&source=en&target=fr

The error was.

Language not included in your current plan.

fr is not included in your current plan?

Comment: I'll confirm what is going on although my plan should have English, Spanish, and French.

Comment: I tried another website and it works http://api.yandex.com/translate/ and this one worked right away thank you so much I assumed that I was in the wrong not that the service wasn't activated correctly.

Comment: NP. Good to hear that it is working now. I Starred your question for future reference :D

Comment: hope that it can help you and anyone else who has a similar problem.